Move subset of videos from one playlist to another
Many videos show how to add all videos in one playlist to another.  I want to move a subset of videos from one playlist to another.  If try to do this by adding all videos from one playlist to another, I would spend a significant time deleting the subset from the original playlist and deleting videos from outside the subset in the destination playlist.  Is there any way to move selected videos between playlists?
This answer seems to no longer apply (I provide a comment).  I also ran across a video (which I can no longer find) where the user can select multiple videos from a playlist via adjacent checkboxes, but that also seems to be gone from the YouTub web interface.
